# How to do multiple recurring payments together through Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: php, paypal, opencart, express-checkout, recurring-billing

I have a website in opencart and selling subscriptions/recurring-payments (weekly, monthly, yearly) where customer can add-in-cart/buy more than one subscription/s and pay through PayPal Express Checkout.

When doing the payment, it works for only one/first subscription but not for others (throwing Error: A successful Billing Agreement has already been created for this token.). I understand that. But as per Paypal's documentation, we can execute payments for multiple subscriptions. As I checked, Even opencart's code is written in a way which can perform payments for multiple subscriptions.

Would it be possible? How can I do it? Can a TOKEN be used for multiple recurring payments?

Comment: "it works for only one/first subscription but not for others" Do you mean trying to create a 2nd subscription on the same product again?

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks for your response. My site is having recurring products which user can buy and pay weekly/monthly/yearly. If the user adds one product in cart and process payment, it works well and recurring profile is also created with no issues but if a user adds two products and process payment, it works for one product and not for 2nd and give an error for the 2nd recurring product as mentioned in my original message. I want a user to add multiple products in the cart and buy using PayPal and PayPal must create a separate recurring profile for each product. Kindly suggest. Thanks

Comment: I see, that makes it clear, presumably this is a bug with OpenCart then? Have you checked for it on Github?

Comment: Thanks @PaulFeakins for your response. Yes, may be there is any bug but i am not sure. If we talk about PHP and Paypal only, can a token be used to generate two/multiple recurring profiles on paypal?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know the answer to that one.

Comment: @PaulFeakins, its ok. Thanks